# Laravel project on host server

Tags: php, laravel, web-hosting

I try to deploy my laravel project on host server. So I upload all files contains in my Laravel Project folder on my host server. But when I check with the url, I can't use my project like when I'm on my localhost. I have just the homepage and when I tried to access others pages the server return 404 not found.

I really have no idea what I should do ?

Any suggests, thanks !

Comment: Do you try to access other pages using a button or by typing in their url?

Comment: Are your files within the vendor directory there? You may need to run `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to check while you work to resolve this issue:

**Compatible Environments**

If your host uses web server software (Apache, Nginx, etc) other than the one that you use in your development environment, check the Laravel documentation for information about configuration Laravel to run with your hosts's web server.

**Routing**

Ensure that you deployed your .htaccess file. This file lives in the `public` directory. It is responsible for mapping all of your URLs to the main Laravel router.

**Deployed Files**

Verify that all of your other files on the host server match the files in your development environment. It is not uncommon to miss files or entire directories when deploying a new project.

**Logging**

If your problem still is not resolved, get access to the host's log files and examine the errors that are logged when you try to access your site. You can often find a clue in the log files that will lead you to the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've deployed it onto a non-apache webserver so .htaccess rewrites are not being used.

If its nginx then you need to add the following rewrites to your vhost configuration.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls